# TFS CheckIn Comment Template

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015

I was searching for a way to set a default check-in comment in Visual Studio 2015.

More or less all I found was this 5 year old Question [Team Foundation Server CheckIn Comment Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203543/team-foundation-server-checkin-comment-template).

Is there a way I can prefill the Comment Section within the Pending Changes?

```
[ProjectName][Component]
[Features]

[Bug Fixes]

[Changes]

[Tests]

[Others]
```

And if there is a way to set it for my client, is there also a way of setting it for the all team members.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: It is a bad practice to have a check in cover multiple changes. It is a better practice to associate your checking with Work Items, and this your comment is infered.

Comment: I agree with you, that it is a bad practice to cover more than one work item and probably I expressed myself too vague.
I do not want to fill out all the fields, only the field the work item is related to. The field should help to easily filter over all changes for creating change logs and reports. It may be a better approach to use tags here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build-in way to prefill the comment section within the pending changes.

A workaround is creating your own custom check-in policy to do what you're looking for.First use the Check-In Policy that requires comments,  and then take it one step further which require comments that include a specifically formatted string.
Checking form check-in comments is not a complicated policy to create. Moreover, this is **a way of setting for the all team members**.

Detail steps about how to create custom check-in policy please refer below tutorials:

- [Creating TFS Custom Check-in Policy](http://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html)
- [Creating a custom check-in policy pack that works with multiple
  versions of Visual Studio.](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/01/creating-custom-check-in-policy-pack.html)